# Difference between DETERMINISTIC and PARALLEL_ENABLED with functions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

What is the difference between `deterministic` and the *parallel enable clause* in Oracle functions, in terms of data access restrictions?

Comment: what sort of data access restrictions do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

As described in the [documentation on the CREATE FUNCTION statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370):

> #### DETERMINISTIC
>
> Indicates that the function returns the same result value whenever it
>   is called with the same values for its parameters.
>
> ...
>
> Do not specify this clause to define a function that uses package
>   variables or that accesses the database in any way that might affect
>   the return result of the function. The results of doing so are not
>   captured if the database chooses not to reexecute the function.

and

> #### parallel_enable_clause
>
> Indicates that the function can run from a parallel execution server
>   of a parallel query operation. The function must not use session
>   state, such as package variables, as those variables are not
>   necessarily shared among the parallel execution servers.
>
> ...
>
> - The optional streaming_clause lets you order or cluster the parallel processing by a specified column list.
>
>   - ORDER BY indicates that the rows on a parallel execution server must be locally ordered.
>   - CLUSTER BY indicates that the rows on a parallel execution server must have the same key values as specified by the column_list.

These are two completely different options that should be used if you need them. The difference is absolute, whatever restrictions there might be, as they are not the same thing.